# Implementing the copy constructor of Queue class in terms of stack class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have my stack class in which I implemented a deep copy of the Nodes defined in that class.
Now I have to implement the copy constructor of Queue class which calls the copy constructor of Stack class.

So This is my Stack.h and Stack.C (Im using LINUX):

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include "MyException.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Stack;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Stack<T>&);

template<class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Stack<T>&);

    /*The constructor for the Stack class*/
    Stack();

    /*The copy constructor*/
    Stack(const Stack<T>& other);

    Stack<T>& operator=(const Stack<T>& other);

    ~Stack();

    void push(const T& el);

    T pop();

    bool isEmpty();

private:
    /*The node class.*/
    class Node
    {
        public:
            Node(const T& data, Node* n = 0)
            {
                element = data;
                next = n;
            }

            T element;
            Node* next;
    };

    /*The top of the stack*/
    Node* top;

 };
#include "Stack.C"
#endif
```

you can assume all the methods work fine.

I have a Queue class which is defined like this:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H
#include <iostream>
#include "MyException.h"
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Queue;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Queue<T>&);

template<class T>
class Queue
{
public:
    friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream&,Queue<T>&);

    Queue();

    Queue(const Queue<T>& other);

    Queue<T>& operator=(const Queue<T>& other);

    /*The destructor*/
    ~Queue();

    void enqueue(const T& el);

    T dequeue();

    bool isEmpty();

private:
    /*You must store your elements in this stack*/
    Stack<T>* stack;

};
#include "Queue.C"
#endif
```

I have implemented my copy constructor like this:

```
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(const Queue<T>& other)
 {
Stack<T> *test = new Stack<T>(*other.stack);
 }
```

When I test My copy constructor in Stack class, everything works fine, but When I test my copy constructor in Queue class I get a Segmentation fault, what coult be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Your copy constructor dynamically allocates a new `Stack` and then throws the pointer away?

Comment: and do you assign to `Queue::stack` the `test`?

Comment: This is my copy constructor in stack: 'top = NULL;
   
   const Node* p = other.top;
       Node **pp = &top;
       while (p)
       {
    *pp = new Node(*p);
    p = p->next;
    pp = &(*pp)->next;
       }
       *pp = NULL;'

Comment: Why are you including your implementation (<filename>.C) in your header files?